# Import default styles implemented by the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to style a `span` just like a default checkbox.
Is there any way to import the `styles` implemented by the `browser` and using them in our page!
thanx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Many browser's form field control default styles are not implemented by the browser, but the operating system, taking into consideration the user's preferences / theme etc.

You really need a checkbox if you want it to look like the default checkbox the user will be accustomed to seeing.

What are you even doing?